# Angular JS: JSON data is not getting displayed in ng-Grid

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ng-grid

I have created MVC 4.0 app using Web API which returns data in JSON format (I am serializing object to json using NewtonSoft.Json) and trying to bind data in ng-Grid. I am receiving data in following format:

```
"[{\"Name\":\"FIRST_NAME\",\"Value\":\"FIRST_NAME\"},{\"Name\":\"CURRENT_DATE_TIME\",\"Value\":\"CURRENT_DATE_TIME\"},{\"Name\":\"CLIENTID\",\"Value\":\"CLIENTID\"},{\"Name\":\"CALLMODE\",\"Value\":\"CALLMODE\"}, {\"Name\":\"new 321\",\"Value\":null}]"
```

When i tried to assign same to data: of ng-Grid, each char populated on different row. following is the javascript i have written:

```
var guidesRespApp = angular.module('guidesRespApp', ['ngGrid']);

//Get Data from restful API.
guidesRespApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/api/datadictionary').success(function (thisdata) {
            $scope.myData  =  thisdata;
    });

     $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: '',
        useExternalFilter: true,
    };


    //Setting grid options
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData',
      multiSelect: true,
      filterOptions: { filterText: '', useExternalFilter: false },
      enableRowReordering: false,
      showGroupPanel: false,
      maintainColumnRatios: false,
      groups: [],
      showSelectionCheckbox: true,
      showFooter: true,
      enableColumnResize: true,
      enableColumnReordering: true
    };


//    $scope.totalFilteredItemsLength = function() {
//        //return self.filteredRows.length;
//        };

});
```

If manually assigned like below, data is getting displayed in grid:

```
$scope.myData = [{"Name":"FIRST_NAME","Value":"FIRST_NAME"},{"Name":"CURRENT_DATE_TIME","Value":"CURRENT_DATE_TIME"},{"Name":"CLIENTID","Value":"CLIENTID"},{"Name":"CALLMODE","Value":"CALLMODE"}];
```

can anyone please help me to understand how to fix it? 
Also i wanted to display count of filtered items when i key in values in filtertext.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned on http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ , Data being displayed in the grid is of type array and each element in that array mapped to a row being displayed. So I modified my code like below and it worked for me:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:12143/api/datadictionary').success(function (thisdata) {
    //Convert data to array.
    var myData =  $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(thisdata));
    $scope.myData  =  myData; 
});
```

even `var myData =  $.parseJSON(angular.fromJson(thisdata));` also working. Just we need first to parse the data (for this I used `JSON.parse()`) and then convert to array (for this i used `$.parseJSON()`).

Comment: This saved me hours. I had the same issue. in my case thisdata is response object so I had to use var $scope.myData = $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(thisdata.data)); Thanks C K.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the get callback to one of the following:

```
$http.get('/api/datadictionary').success(function (thisdata) {
        $scope.myData  =  JSON.parse(thisdata);
        // or
        $scope.myData = angular.fromJson(thisdata);
});
```

Reference this with regards to how webapi is returning json.  [ASP.NET WebAPI: How to control string content returned to client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128013/asp-net-webapi-how-to-control-string-content-returned-to-client)

Comment: I had to do this var myData = angular.fromJson(angular.fromJson(data));